# Sitefinity: Unexpected end of file has occurred

Tags: sitefinity

I am hoping someone might be able to answer this question on Sitefinity. This happens when we try and save a page after some changes were made. We are trying to work out why this could be happening because this does work on the localhost installation. Our thinking is that when we send the database back to the client to restore, they need to downgrade from from SQL2008 to SQL2000.

Here's the error...

Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: SettingTypeName, BaseSettingValue, ArrayOfBaseSettingValue. Line 1, position 4001.

Many thanks!

> Server Error in '/' Application.
> Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: SettingTypeName, BaseSettingValue, ArrayOfBaseSettingValue. Line 1, position 4001.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 
>
> Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: SettingTypeName, BaseSettingValue, ArrayOfBaseSettingValue. Line 1, position 4001.
>
> Source Error: 
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
> Stack Trace: 
>
>  [XmlException: Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: SettingTypeName, BaseSettingValue, ArrayOfBaseSettingValue. Line 1, position 4001.]
>    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e) +76
>    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) +126
>    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, String res, String arg) +18
>    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements() +254
>    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent() +3977055
>    System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +45
>    System.Xml.XmlReader.InternalReadContentAsString() +181
>    System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadContentAsString() +37
>    System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementContentAsString() +35
>    Telerik.Cms.Engine.Design.SettingsListConverter.GetSettingTypes(String serializedSettings) +169
>    Telerik.Cms.Engine.Design.SettingsListConverter.DeserializeDesignerSettings(String settingsCollection) +105
>    Telerik.Cms.Engine.Design.SettingsListConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value) +62
>    System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(String text) +55
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.WebControlBase.LoadControl(Control control, PropertyDescriptorCollection properties) +180
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.CmsWebControl.LoadControl(Control control, PropertyDescriptorCollection properties) +9
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.WebControlBase.LoadControl(TemplateControl template, Control& control) +287
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.WebControlBase.LoadControl(TemplateControl template) +27
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.WebControlBase.LoadControl() +12
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.StagedPage.GetRewriterServiceType(CmsWebControl ctrl) +83
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.StagedPage.Copy(StagedPage source, PageContentBase target) +693
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.StagedPage.Publish() +220
>    Telerik.Cms.Data.StagedPage.CheckIn() +365
>    Telerik.Cms.Web.UI.ToolBar.Button_Command(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) +123
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +108
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +135
>    System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +175
>    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3620; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any custom aspx controls in sitefinity or have you edited any of the base sitefinity page widgets where you might be missing an end quote on an attribute?

e.g.

```
<SettingTypeName myAttribute="heresAnAttribute >blah blah blah</SettingTypeName>
```

If I remember correctly, the lack of the closing end quote gives a similar error to what you're seeing...